# What is the equivalent of @OneToOne(optional=false) in hbm.xml files?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, hbm

We use hibernate 3 with some hbm.xml files. 
Recently, we found that a one-to-one association (based on primary keys) is not loaded lazily and thus, making some memory issues.
After a little search, we found the solution for annotation-based hibernate configurations:
Since the other side of the association is always present, it is only needed to add @OneToOne(optional=false) before the corresponding property in the java class.

The problem is that we have not used annotations!
We tried to add the attribute optional="false" in the  tag, which resulted in some xml parsing exceptions.
We are looking for the equivalent of @OneToOne(optional=false) in hbm.xml files.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the source, it looks like `constrained=true` is equivalent.